# borrow_mut() on my RefCell-like structure doesn't work

Tags: rust

I try to write my own `RefCell`-like mutable memory location but without runtime borrow checking (no overhead). I adopted the code architecture from `RefCell` (and `Ref`, and `RefMut`). I can call `.borrow()` without problems but if I call `.borrow_mut()` then the rust compiler says `cannot borrow as mutable`. I don't see the problem, my `.borrow_mut()` impl looks fine?

#### code that fails:

```
let real_refcell= Rc::from(RefCell::from(MyStruct::new()));
let nooverhead_refcell = Rc::from(NORefCell::from(MyStruct::new()));

// works
let refmut_refcell = real_refcell.borrow_mut();

// cannot borrow as mutable
let refmut_norefcell = nooverhead_refcell.borrow_mut();
```

#### `norc.rs` (No Overhead RefCell)

```
use crate::norc_ref::{NORefMut, NORef};
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;
use std::borrow::Borrow;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct NORefCell<T: ?Sized> {
    value: UnsafeCell<T>
}

impl<T> NORefCell<T> {

    pub fn from(t: T) -> NORefCell<T> {
        NORefCell {
            value: UnsafeCell::from(t)
        }
    }

    pub fn borrow(&self) -> NORef<'_, T> {
        NORef {
            value: unsafe { &*self.value.get() }
        }
    }

    pub fn borrow_mut(&mut self) -> NORefMut<'_, T> {
        NORefMut {
            value: unsafe { &mut *self.value.get() }
        }
    }

}
```

#### `norc_ref.rs` (data structure returned by `NORefCell.borrow[_mut]()`

```
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct NORef<'b, T: ?Sized + 'b> {
    pub value: &'b T,
}

impl<T: ?Sized> Deref for NORef<'_, T> {
    type Target = T;

    #[inline]
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        self.value
    }
}

/// No Overhead Ref Cell: Mutable Reference
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct NORefMut<'b, T: ?Sized + 'b> {
    pub value: &'b mut T,
}

impl<T: ?Sized> Deref for NORefMut<'_, T> {
    type Target = T;

    #[inline]
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        self.value
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized> DerefMut for NORefMut<'_, T> {

    #[inline]
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        self.value
    }
}
```

Comment: `NORefCell::borrow_mut()`takes `&mut self`, which requires a `DerefMut` on the `Rc` in which it is wrapped. This won't work because `Rc` does not give mutable references just by asking nicely (you need it to check if the reference count is exactly one, otherwise there would be multiple mutable borrows). `borrow_mut` has to take `&self` instead of `&mut self`.

Comment: As a general comment, be aware that you are building an automated foot-removal-gun with integrated self-triggering.

Comment: There's no point in having `NORef` and `NORefMut` if they don't have `Drop` glue; you may as well just return `&T` and `&mut T`. Which is technically safe, since `borrow_mut` takes `&mut self`, but if you change that the footgun comes into play.

Comment: @user2722968 I mainly did this just for fun and to understand how specific rust concepts and patterns work. I wont necessarily use it in production! But yes, you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NORefCell::borrow_mut()` takes `&mut self`, which requires a `DerefMut` on the `Rc` in which it is wrapped. This won't work because `Rc` does not give mutable references just by asking nicely (you need it to check if the reference count is exactly one, otherwise there would be multiple mutable borrows).

`borrow_mut` has to take `&self` instead of `&mut self`.

---

As mentioned in my comment: What you are basically doing is providing a safe-looking abstraction around an `UnsafeCell`. This is incredibly dangerous. Notice the docs regarding `UnsafeCell`:

> The compiler makes optimizations based on the knowledge that &T is not mutably aliased or mutated, and that &mut T is unique. UnsafeCell is the **only** core language feature to work around the restriction that &T may not be mutated.

You are providing a thin wrapper around this powerful object, with no `unsafe` on the API-boundary. The "No-overhead-RefCell" is really a "no-trigger-guard-foot-gun". It does work, yet be warned about its dangers.

Comment: Shouldn't it be safe - in theory - if I have good (integration) test coverage with `RefCell` and no panic is thrown, that I "safely" can replace `RefCell` by `NORefCell`?

Comment: I'd say No. The potential problems are with the users of `NORefCell`, not it's implementation. Notice that your wrapper is essentially a very long way of [saying](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/cell.rs.html#1539) `... as *const T as *mut T`. There are absolutely no safeguards from this point on and the compiler will *not* tell you about potential problems. Unrelated to `Cell`, see [here](https://github.com/libra/libra/pull/1949) for an example of how things can get very ugly very quickly with raw pointers. So IMHO it's not worth the negligible performance gain.